# Why doesn't the file get deleted and renamed?

Tags: java, file, io

I have two models in my program, Bus and Learner.
Each is stored in a txt file, name Busses.txt and Learners.txt, respectively.
I am experiencing an issue where the method to delete a learner entry works, but the method to delete a bus entry does not, even though the code is practically identical.

**Learner delete method:**

```
public void deleteLearner(String ID) {
    removeBlankLines("Learners.txt");
    File oldFile = new File("Learners.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("tempFile.txt");

    String removeKey = ID;

    String LearnerID;
    String nameSurname;
    boolean status;
    String busOfLearner;
    String line;
    String lineToKeep;
    try {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Learners.txt"));

        while (scFile.hasNext()) {          
            line = scFile.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");
            LearnerID = scLine.next();
            nameSurname = scLine.next();
            status = scLine.nextBoolean();
            if (scLine.hasNext()) {
                busOfLearner = scLine.next();
            } else {
                busOfLearner = "";
            }

            if (!LearnerID.equalsIgnoreCase(removeKey)) {
                lineToKeep = LearnerID + "#" + nameSurname + "#" + status + "#" + busOfLearner + "\n";

                FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
                BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                bWriter.write(lineToKeep);

                bWriter.close();
                fWriter.close();
            }  
            scLine.close();
        }
        scFile.close();
        boolean successfulDelete = oldFile.delete();
        File transfer = new File("Learners.txt");
        boolean successfulRename = tempFile.renameTo(transfer);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occured deleting a learner record " + e);
    }
}
```

**Delete bus method:**

```
public void deleteBus(String removeBusName) {
    removeBlankLinesBus("Busses.txt");
    File oldFile = new File("Busses.txt");
    File newFile = new File("NewBusFile.txt");

    String deleteKey = removeBusName;

    String currentBusName;
    int currentNumSeats;
    String currentPickLocation;
    String currentDropLocation;
    String currentPickTime;
    String currentDropTime;
    String line;
    String lineToKeep;
    try {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("Busses.txt"));

        while (scFile.hasNext()) {                
            line = scFile.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("#");

            currentBusName = scLine.next();
            currentNumSeats = scLine.nextInt();
            currentPickLocation = scLine.next();
            currentDropLocation = scLine.next();
            currentPickTime = scLine.next();
            currentDropTime = scLine.next();                

            if (!currentBusName.equalsIgnoreCase(deleteKey)) {
                lineToKeep = currentBusName + "#" + currentNumSeats + "#" + currentPickLocation + "#" + currentDropLocation + "#" + currentPickTime + "#" + currentDropTime + "\n";

                FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(newFile,true);
                BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                bWriter.write(lineToKeep);

                bWriter.close();
                fWriter.close();
            }
            scLine.close();    
        }            
        scFile.close();

        boolean successfulDelete = oldFile.delete();
        File transfer = new File("Busses.txt");
        boolean successfulRename = newFile.renameTo(transfer);

    }        
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An error has occured deleting " + removeBusName + " from the file: " + e);
    } 

}
```

**Problem:**
With the delete bus method, the old file doesn't get deleted and the temporary or new file doesn't get renamed to the original file. 
I am very confident that all files, streams, scanners, etc. are closed, as it is exactly the same as I did in the delete learner method, which does work and the files are deleted and renamed in the learner delete method as it should.
Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: **Implementation of methods:**
**Learner:**

```
System.out.println(myController.PrintLearnerArr(myController.LoadLearner("Learners.txt")));
String delete = "0210045112055";
myController.deleteLearner(delete);
System.out.println(myController.PrintLearnerArr(myController.LoadLearner("Learners.txt")));
```

**Bus:**

```
System.out.println(myController.PrintBusArr(myController.LoadBus("Busses.txt")));
String deleteKey = "deleteme";
myController.deleteBus(deleteKey);
System.out.println(myController.PrintBusArr(myController.LoadBus("Busses.txt")));
```

Comment: I suggest that you check the values of successfulDelete and successfulRename in each call, and also check that implementation of removeBlankLinesBus closes any streams that it opens on the undelying files.  Perhaps that may be the cause of delete/renameTo fails.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist. 
I ran the method without the removeBlankLinesBus to determine whether it may cause the problem, but it makes no difference to the result. The removeBlankLinesBus also does close all and any streams.
I checked the values of successfulDelete and successfulRename, both returned false, which makes sense considering the problem. I can't seem to pinpoint why this would occur as the return values in the delete Learner method return true, as it should as that method works as expected.